# Semiconcavity estimate for the squared distance on a compact Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry, optimal-transportation, geodesics

I am currently reading [this paper](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Enicola.gigli/Site/Publications_files/Inverse.pdf) on the Riemannian structure of the Wasserstein space over a compact Riemannian manifold (my question doesn't concern the Wasserstein metric), specifically Section 4.1, and I have a question about one point in the argument of Theorem 4.2.

Let $(M, \langle \, , \, \rangle)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with induced distance function $d$. Then the squared distance $d^2(\cdot,\cdot)$ satisfies the following semiconcavity inequality: there is a constant $C > 0$ such that, for any $x \in M$ and any minimizing, constant speed geodesic $\gamma(t)$ on $[0,1]$,
\begin{equation*}
d^2(x,\gamma(t)) \geq (1-t)d^2(x,\gamma(0)) + td^2(x,\gamma(1)) - Ct(1-t)d^2(\gamma(0),\gamma(1)) \, . 
\end{equation*}

This is proved in Lemma 3.2 of [this paper](https://www.math.kyoto-u.ac.jp/preprint/2006/19ohta.pdf) (the author of the first paper I mentioned cites a later version, wherein it is instead Lemma 3.3) for the more general setting of compact Alexandrov spaces, where it is also shown that the constant $C$ is $\sqrt{1 + (\text{diam}\,M)^2}$. Gigli cites this inequality in his proof of Theorem 4.2 to argue the following:
\begin{equation*}
|v_2|^2 + d^2(\exp_x(v_1),\exp_x(v_2)) - C(1-t)|v_1|^2 \leq \frac{1}{t}\left(d^2(\exp_x(tv_1),\exp_x(v_2)) - |v_2|^2\right) \, ,
\end{equation*}
where $x \in M, v_1,v_2 \in T_xM$, and $v_2$ is the initial velocity of a minimizing geodesic. **Crucially to my question, $v_1$ is not assumed to be the initial velocity of a minimizing geodesic**.

I believe that the author intends to use the stated semiconcavity inequality with $x = \exp_x(v_2)$ (the $x$'s are different... I'm trying to exactly follow the notation of the paper) and $\gamma(t) = \exp_x(tv_1)$. In this case, $d(x,\gamma(0)) = |v_2|$ since $v_2$ is the initial velocity of a minimizing geodesic. However, $v_1$ is not. Yet the author asserts that this inequality follows from the semiconcavity inequality *as stated above*.

The author is actually asserting the weaker inequality:
\begin{equation*}
d^2(x,\gamma(t)) \geq (1-t)d^2(x,\gamma(0)) + td^2(x,\gamma(1)) - Ct(1-t)|\dot{\gamma}(0)|_{\gamma(0)}^2\, ,
\end{equation*}
with $x \in M$ and $\gamma(t)$ a constant-speed geodesic on $[0,1]$ (not necessarily minimizing).

Is this weaker inequality true? If so, what would be a good reference for it (I don't need someone to go through the effort to write a proof, unless it's simple to prove)? I believe it could be true (see below).

If not, is there a counter-example?

**My intuition for why it should be true**

Consider first $M = S^1$ with the usual round metric. So $\text{diam}\, M = \pi$. To violate the inequality, I'd want to make $d(x,\gamma(t))$ and $|\dot{\gamma}(0)|$ as small as possible, while making $d(x,\gamma(0))$ and $d(x,\gamma(1))$ as large as possible. In the case of $S^1$, we can take $\gamma$ to be a closed geodesic, with speed $|\dot{\gamma}(0)| = 2 \pi$ (the smallest possible speed). Let $x$ be antipodal to $\gamma(0)$. Then $d(x,\gamma(1/2)) = 0$, $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma(1)$ are as far from $x$ as possible: they are $\pi$ away from $x$. Then I have, at $t = 1/2$ (the time which minimizes the right-hand side):
\begin{equation*}
(1-t)d^2(x,\gamma(0)) + td^2(x,\gamma(1)) - Ct(1-t)d^2|\dot{\gamma}(0)|^2 = \pi^2 - \pi^2 \sqrt{1 + \pi^2} \leq 0 = d^2(x,\gamma(t)) \, . 
\end{equation*}

So it seems like the inequality *does* hold on $S^1$ (though this isn't a complete proof).

My reasoning for a general (still compact) manifold would be as follows: for any closed geodesic with length $2L$ (so speed is close to $2L$ as well). Then take $x = \gamma(1/2)$ so that $d(x,\gamma(0)) = d(x,\gamma(1)) = L$, and observe that the right-hand side is
\begin{equation*}
L^2 - L^2\sqrt{1 + (\text{diam}\, M)^2} < 0 = d^2(x,\gamma(1/2)) \, . 
\end{equation*}

Perhaps looking at closed geodesics isn't the way to go though. If we take non-closed geodesics, then we could make $|\dot{\gamma}(0)|$ smaller, after all. My reasoning for looking at closed geodesics was that doing so allows me to make the squared distance terms as small/large as possible.